# isodate.duration.Duration: Duration comparison is inconsistent?

Tags: python, duration, isodate

This is copied straight out of my console:

```
>>> import isodate
>>> import datetime
```

First statements are as expected. 1 month duration not longer than 10 years duration.

```
>>> duration = isodate.parse_duration("P1M")
>>> duration > isodate.duration.Duration(0, 0, 0, years=10, months=0)
False
```

But then I get **1 month duration is longer than 10 years duration all of a sudden.**

```
>>> duration = isodate.parse_duration("P1M")
>>> isinstance(duration, isodate.Duration)
True
>>> duration > isodate.duration.Duration(0, 0, 0, years=10, months=0)
True
>>> duration
isodate.duration.Duration(0, 0, 0, years=0, months=1)
```

What is happening here that I don't understand.

Comment: I get `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'Duration' and 'Duration'`

Comment: @jonrsharpe I get that too. Op, have you updated to the latest version of isodate (0.6.0?)

Comment: strange. yeah I have 0.6.0

Comment: You can see here there are no `__lt__` or `__gt__` methods https://github.com/gweis/isodate/blob/master/src/isodate/duration.py#L67 -- are you working off a fork or something? Where did you get your `isodate` from?

Comment: What explains that I can use > and <? I'm pretty new to Python. BTW: it seems that I might only be getting that a month is longer than 10 years when I import datetime. I don't know though. I have just tested a few times.

Comment: If you're new to python why are you using isodate? Use the inbuilt `datetime` or [`arrow`](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). These are much more complete and better maintained.

Comment: What version of python are you using? `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: @FHTMitchell: import sys; print(sys.version)
2.7.15 (default, Aug 22 2018, 16:36:18)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)]

Comment: My next suggestion will be to move to python 3.7. 2.7 is outdated (and has been since 2010) and will no longer be maintained beyond 2020.

Comment: `isodate` is still in beta and almost totally undocumented. Consider using `dateutil` instead.

Comment: Do you get correct comparisons when month and year are zero? Note that isodate has a datetime.timedelta for the other components, but since month and year are not precise terms, they are not comparable, and are not included in datetime.timedelta