# Simplify code dealing with time and duration that currently uses datetime and isodate?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, duration

The code below is supposed to:

- parse an input string to some kind of duration
- validate that the duration is not empty, not negative, not longer than 10 years

Example of input strings are:

```
duration_string = "P10W"
duration_string = "P1Y"
```

Here is the code

```
    duration = isodate.parse_duration(duration_string)

    if isinstance(duration, datetime.timedelta):
        if not duration > datetime.timedelta(0):
            raise Exception('duration invalid')
        if duration > datetime.timedelta(3660):
            raise Exception('duration cannot be longer than 10 years')
    elif isinstance(duration, isodate.Duration):
        if not duration > 0:
            raise Exception('duration invalid')
        if duration > isodate.duration.Duration(0, 0, 0, years=10, months=0):
            log.debug("duration %s isodate %s" % (duration, isodate.duration.Duration(0, 0, 0, years=10, months=0)))
            raise Exception('duration cannot be longer than 10 years')
```

Is there an easier way to do this than the monstrocity I have produced?

In addition to needing simplification, the line `duration > isodate.duration.Duration(0, 0, 0, years=10, months=0)` does not work.

I am using Python 2.7

Comment: Are 30 days shorter or longer than a month (think February and August)? Comparisons between these values make no sense. If you want to compare lengths of time, you have to get them into consistent units first.

Comment: @FHTMitchell: That's a good point. Exactness if not super important. I would be fine with 365D=12M=52W=1Y

Comment: OK, except if `52 weeks == 365 days` then `1 week == 7.019230769230769 days`. Is that really what you want? Can you see why there is no standard functionality to do this?

Comment: @FHTMitchell: I can't think of a different way to limit the duration to some sensible amount. Can you think of a better way?

Comment: Ask for an input in seconds or days only? What is this duration referring to? Is it a duration from today (as in we will do this for 6 months from now?). Is there some date you can associate this with?

Comment: @FHTMitchell: Nope, no date. It is the duration of campaign codes. The end date is calculated the moment someone starts the campaign. The only reason I want a limitation is I want to avoid user entering 100000000000000 which then causes an error in the api where the campaign is started and the end date is calculated.

Comment: That's fair but how is the user entering the duration? 100000000000000 what? 100000000000000 nanoseconds is just over a day.

Comment: You say your isodate.duration comparison does not work. Can you provide an example of a duration value which illustrates this case? (show your imports, too)

Comment: @KennyOstrom: See my other thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52332509/isodate-duration-duration-duration-comparison-is-inconsistent where I test that operation with the same input and get different results. I don't understand why.

Comment: @FHTMitchell: The user chooses day|week|month|year and then types a number. This is parsed to {"P"}{number}{"D"|"W"|"M"|"Y"} (ISO8601 format)

Comment: The code looks clear and not in need of any simplification. Maybe you could have different text in the different error paths (e.g. "datetime duration invalid") The other thread indicates that isodate is a potentially incorrect third party library -- I'm not going there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so if you absolutely must use isodate duration parsing, keep the `isodate` library. I would however mention that the isodate library is incomplete, has a number of poor design decisions and is just generally bad.

However if you must use their parsing tool, this is probably a good way.

```
import isodate
import functools

@functools.total_ordering  # if we implement < ==, will implement <=, >, >=
class Duration(isodate.Duration):
    # inherit from isodate.Duration -- gives us ==

    # constants 
    seconds_in_day = 60**2 * 24
    approx_days_in_month = 30
    approx_days_in_year = 365

    def approx_total_seconds(self):
        """approx total seconds in duration"""
        # self.months and self.years are stored as `Decimal`s for some reason...
        return self.tdelta.total_seconds() \
               + float(self.months) * self.approx_days_in_month *  self.seconds_in_day \
               + float(self.years) * self.approx_days_in_year * self.seconds_in_day

    def __lt__(self, other):
        """defines self < other"""
        if not isinstance(other, Duration):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.approx_total_seconds() < other.approx_total_seconds()

    @classmethod
    def parse_duration(cls, datestring):
        """a version of isodate.parse_duration that returns out class"""

        iso_dur = isodate.parse_duration(datestring)

        # iso_date.parse_duration can return either a Duration or a timedelta...
        if isinstance(iso_dur, isodate.Duration):
            return cls(seconds=iso_dur.tdelta.total_seconds(),
                       months=iso_dur.months, years=iso_dur.years)
        else:
            return cls(seconds=iso_dur.total_seconds())


ten_weeks = Duration.parse_duration('P10W')
one_year = Duration.parse_duration('P1Y')

print(ten_weeks.approx_total_seconds())
print(one_year.approx_total_seconds())

print(ten_weeks < one_year)
print(ten_weeks > one_year)
```

Outputs

```
6048000.0
31536000.0
True
False
```

---

If you don't need the isodate parsing (and I suspect you don't) you could just do

```
@functools.TotalOrdering
class ApproxTimeDelta:

    approx_days_in_week = 7
    approx_days_in_month = 30
    approx_days_in_year = 365

    def __init__(self, days, weeks, months, years):
        self.days = days + \
                    weeks * self.approx_days_in_week + \
                    months * self.approx_days_in_month + \
                    years * self.approx_days_in_year

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.days == other.days

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.days < other.days
```

and pass the years/months/weeks/days as integers and compare as before.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that I ended up using:

```
    if isinstance(duration, datetime.timedelta):
        if not duration > 0:
            raise Exception('duration invalid')
        if duration > 3650:
            raise Exception('maximum duration is 3650 days')
    elif isinstance(duration, isodate.Duration):
        if duration.years > 10:
            raise Exception('maximum duration is 10 years')
        if duration.months > 120:
            raise Exception('maximum duration is 120 months')
```